# How to handle blank email address in actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Due to data inconsistency issues, I get email addresses like `" "` this in recipients. If `ActionMailer` encounters any of such, it just eliminates the whole recipient list and sends to no one.

What is the best way to handle such cases without having to fix data? something that can be checked through logic? I dont want to use

```
to_list.reject{|email| email==" "}
```

or something of that sort.

Comment: How do you get the list of email addresses?

Comment: And what DB engine you are using ? Like MySql, Postgresql etc

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing anything about your 'logic' - But yes if these addresses are entered via a form, the controller would be a place to filter for invalid addresses an generate according feedback. But then again why don't you want to do s.th. of 'this sort' - you do have to detect invalid addresses somehow after all..

Comment: If you are 'in the mailer' it's obviously too late - so there is logically no way to fix things without tampering with the recipients - since as far as we know, it's all you got

Comment: I dont want to use reject/select on array of email ids because I am wondering if actionmailer provides any such function inbuilt that can validate and isolate blank or invalid email addresses itself, and discard them before actually actually triggering the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this to your array:

```
list = ["abc@gmail.com", "", "xyz@gmail.com", nil]
list -= ["", nil]
```

This will removed empty and nil element from you recipient list array like that:

```
["abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com"]
```

Comment: Another way to do this is to say `list = list.reject(&:blank?)`

Comment: And they specified they didn't want to use this sort of solution.